# Cascading mutate in R

Tags: r, text, character, tidyverse, dplyr

So I have a data frame that I am trying to clean up to mark which characters have which lines in a song:

```
                  artist track_title                     lyric     character
1  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue             ["Work Song"] ["Work Song"]
2  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue               [PRISONERS]   [PRISONERS]
3  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue       Aaah, aah, aaaahhhh         false
4  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue      Look down, look down         false
5  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue Don't look 'em in the eye         false
6  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue      Look down, look down         false
7 Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue You're here until you die         false
8 Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue             [PRISONER #1] [PRISONER #1]
```

What I want to do is somehow check if the value for `character` is false, and if so, continually look up until I get the 1st instance, or to check if the value blow the current `character` value is `false`, and if so take that previous `character` value.

I've tried using `lead()` and `lag()` like below:

`lyrics[c(1:3,8:15),] %>%
    mutate(character = if_else(str_detect(lyric, "\\[|\\]") == TRUE,lyric,'false'),
           character2 = if_else(character == 'false',lag(character),character)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()`

but I only get something akin to this:

```
                    artist track_title                     lyric     character
1  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue             ["Work Song"] ["Work Song"]
2  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue               [PRISONERS]   [PRISONERS]
3  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue       Aaah, aah, aaaahhhh   [PRISONERS]
4  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue Don't look 'em in the eye         false
5  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue      Look down, look down         false
6  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue You're here until you die         false
7  Claude-Michel Schönberg    Prologue             [PRISONER #1] [PRISONER #1]
```

It only does this once, and I'm trying to make this cascade down the column.

Comment: You can turn the false values to NAs and use na.locf from the zoo package. Unfortunately I'm on my phone and can't test it, but it should work

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!